# mysql conditional where clause if value is null or not

Tags: mysql

Given:

```
id  | f1 |   f2
---------------
 1  |  x |    y
 2  |  x | null
```

I need to select row 1 if my search terms are var1 = x and var2 = y but 2 if var1 = x and var2 is null.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT @var1:='x', @var2:=NULL;
SELECT  *
FROM datatable
WHERE f1 = @country
AND CASE @var2
    WHEN NOT NULL THEN f2 = @var2
    ELSE f2 = @var2
END;
```

Also tried:

```
SELECT @var1:='x', @var2:=NULL;
SELECT  *
FROM datatable
WHERE f1 = @var1
AND f2 = IFNULL(@var2,NULL);
```

Do I need a union to achieve this or am I missing a small tweak that would make what I've tried work?

Comment: var1 country currency - eh?

Comment: sorry - copy pase without editing - have updated post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just safely NULL-compare with [`<=>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to):

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  datatable 
WHERE 
  f1<=>@var1 
  AND 
-- this will compare with NULL properly:
  f2<=>@var2
```

That's like:

```
mysql> select @var1,@var2;
+-------+-------+
| @var1 | @var2 |
+-------+-------+
| x     | y     |
+-------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test where f1<=>@var1 and f2<=>@var2;
+------+------+------+
| id   | f1   | f2   |
+------+------+------+
|    1 | x    | y    |
+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```